# How cursor selects a database in django

Tags: python, django, cursor

I have a question for cursor in python, if I have more than one database in my settings and I want to open a cursor in a function that will export data to excel file with openpyxl.
My question is how my cursor will know which database to connect and how this does it.

Thanks in advance

```
DATABASES  = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'default',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
},
'test1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test1',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5433',
},
'test2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test2',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will use the `default` database. If you need to use a different database use:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()
```

From the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-raw-cursors-with-multiple-databases).